# Launch a single python script as different processes differing by command line arguments

Tags: python, linux, process

I have python script that takes command line arguments. The way I get the command line arguments is by reading a mongo database. I need to iterate over the mongo query and launch a different process for the single script with different command line arguments from the mongo query.

Key is, I need the launched processes to be:

- separate processes share nothing
- when killing the process, I need to be able to kill them all easily.

I think the command `killall -9 script.py` would work and satisfies the second constraint.

**Edit 1**

From the answer below, the `launcher.py` program looks like this

```
def main():


    symbolPreDict = initializeGetMongoAllSymbols()
    keys = sorted(symbolPreDict.keys())

    for symbol in keys:
            # Display key.
            print(symbol)
            command = ['python', 'mc.py', '-s', str(symbol)]
            print command
            subprocess.call(command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

The problem is that `mc.py` has a call that blocks

```
receiver = multicast.MulticastUDPReceiver ("192.168.0.2", symbolMCIPAddrStr, symbolMCPort ) 
while True: 
    try:
        b = MD()

        data = receiver.read() # This blocks
        ...
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

When I run the launcher, it just executes one of the `mc.py` (there are at least 39). How do I modify the launcher program to say "run the launched script in background" so that the script returns to the launcher to launch more scripts?

**Edit 2**

The problem is solved by replacing `subprocess.call(command)` with `subprocess.Popen(command)`

One thing I noticed though, if I say `ps ax | grep mc.py`, the PID seem to be all different. I don't think I care since I can kill them all pretty easily with `killall`.

[Correction] kill them with `pkill -f xxx.py`

Comment: You probably want multiprocessing not subprocess https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Aren't these running on their own process?

Comment: Yes but horses for courses, if you want to run and control multiple processes then use multiprocessing, hence the name.

Comment: Well, what does it buy me?

Comment: These scripts do not communicate or share anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options for launching scripts from a script. The easiest are probably to use the `subprocess` or `os` modules.

I have done this several times to launch things to separate nodes on a cluster. Using `os` it might look something like this:

```
import os
for i in range(len(operations)):
     os.system("python myScript.py {:} {:} > out.log".format(arg1,arg2))
```

using killall you should have no problem terminating processes spawned this way.

Another option is to use `subprocess` which has got a wide range of features and is much more flexible than `os.system`. An example might look like:

```
import subprocess
for i in range(len(operations)):
    command = ['python','myScript.py','arg1','arg2']
    subprocess.call(command)
```

In both of these methods, the processes are independent and share nothing other than a parent PID.

Comment: I gave you credit because you answered my question. Please See Edit 1 for an unanticipated problem.

Comment: I figured it out Popen.

Comment: call blocks so you won't be running one process  untll the previous process returns

Comment: That does not appear to be the case. See Edit 2.

Comment: Popen will definitely work. But as a note to others reading this question, so will `os.system()` by simply adding an `&` to the end of the command. On UNIX/LINUX/UNIX-like systems the `&` runs a process in the background. For example try `os.system('sleep 3')` versus `os.system('sleep 3 &')`